# Spring Boot JPA Save not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am migrating Spring Boot 1.2.4 running in Websphere  to Spring Boot 1.5.9. This application uses Spring Data JPA with Hibernate. After migration one of the save method is not working as expected. When I try to insert a new row in table getting an exception with SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, but same code works fine with Spring Boot 1.2.4.

My Pom.xml looks like below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
```

Spring Boot 1.2.4 configuration looks like below.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    @Repository
    public interface MyDataRepository extends CurdRepository<MyEntity,Long>{}

    @Service
    public class MyDataService{

   @Autowired
   private MyDataRepository myDataRepository;

   public void insertMyDate(MyData myData){
     myDataRepository.save(myData)
   } 

   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name="MYDATA" ,schema="MYSCHEMA")
   public class MyData implements java.io.Serializable {

   private int memberId;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private Date dateofBirth;

   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Id 
   @Column(name="MEMBER_ID",uniqueue=true,nullable=false)
   public int getMemberId(){
    return this.memberId;
   }

  public void setMemberId(int memberId){
   return this.memberId = memberId;
   }

   //Geter and Setters
   }
```

With same code when executing save method in 1.5.9 getting below exception.

could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Hard to help if you don't share some code

Comment: @Pedro added sample code which working in Spring Boot 1.2.4 and Websphere but same is not working in Spring Boot 1.5.9.Getting exception while generating squence.

Comment: Could you pls add the DDLs?

Comment: Try enabling query logging to see the generated query: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) not been able to generate Sequence number if I change @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) it works.

Comment: Please add the table DDL and the full stack trace of the exception (formatted as code if I may ask).

Comment: What database are you using? AUTO should be avoided. Probably it tries to create a table hibernate_sequence and your database user is not allowed to create tables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this hibernate-entitymanager dependency becz you are using repository to save data